# Mongoose query: how to pass a variable

Tags: node.js, find, mongoose, where-clause

How do I pass `'n'` instead of hard coded `'5'` in `Xcom.find({ $where : "this.NIC_No == '5'" }` below?

```
exports.query_by_nic = function ( req, res ){
  var n = req.body.NIC_No;
  console.log(n); //n prints correctly as expected
  Xcom.find({ $where : "this.NIC_No == '5'" }, function ( err, xcoms ){ //works with '5' but how do I query for 'n'?
     res.render( 'query_by_nic', {
        title   : 'Query by NIC',
        xcoms   : xcoms
    });
    console.log(err);
    console.log(xcoms);
  });
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? I see no reason why concating n in place of 5 would not work. That said, since you're using mongoose the correct syntax should be `Xcom.find({ 'NIC_No': n }, ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
Xcom.find({ $where : "this.NIC_No == '" + variableThatContainsNumber + "'" }, function ( err, xcoms ){
    ...
});
```

Or even better:

```
Xcom.find({NIC_No: variableThatContainsNumber}, function(err, doc) {
    ...
});
```

The second one is much better because it does not require JavaScript execution within MongoDB.

Comment: Agreed.  You shouldn't use `$where` unless you have no other option because of the performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. They helped

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
{ $where : "this.NIC_No == '" + n + "'" }
```

Although you're passing in a value that the user could directly set, which probably isn't a great idea. If `n` is always a number, be safer to make sure using something like:

```
 var n = parseInt(req.body.NIC_No, 10);
```

And if `n` is always a number, you don't need to put it in quotes in the query either:

```
{ $where : "this.NIC_No == " + n }
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew! { $where : "this.NIC_No == '" + n + "'" } worked